# I have a 3 year German Aufenthaltserlaubnis in IT and I want to renegotiate my hours. What should I look out for?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany

I'm a US expat holding a 3-year German Aufenthaltserlaubnis, and an unlimited work contract as a software developer.

**I'm planning to re-negotiate my working contract to reduce my working hours** from 40 hours to something like 24.

As I understand it, [per TzBfG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/tzbfg/__8.html), because I've worked at my company for longer than 6 months, and because it employs at least 15 people, I have the right to request part-time hours, and my employer must negotiate with me, unless they can cite significant "operational reasons" why the request can't be accepted.

**I'm unsure whether reduced working hours and reduced salary could have implications for my visa status.**

*Minimum salary?* For instance, I know that the [EU Blue Card for "MINT" workers requires a minimum salary of 37,752 €](http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/fileadmin/content/make-it-in-germany/PDF/Arbeiten/Guide-to-Working-in-Germany_en.pdf). So far I've found [no such minimum for the Aufenthaltserlaubnis.](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/mindestgehalt-fuer-unbefristete-aufenthaltserlaubnis) Does such a minimum salary, or for example a minimum hourly work week, exist for the Aufenthaltserlaubnis?

*Are there other concerns I haven't listed?* For instance, will I need to contact the Ausländerbehörde when my contract changes? Would my visa status need to be reviewed? Could it adversely affect me when it's time to renew my visa?

*Separately, I would not be at all surprised if they attempt to refuse my request,* since I am a key member of a small team. However [a second about TzBfG suggests that it is very difficult](http://www.frankfurt-main.ihk.de/recht/themen/arbeitsrecht/teilzeitarbeitsgesetz/) for an employer to prove that the costs / consequences of reduced working hours are "disproportionate." Does anyone have experience with this process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically the law is 'on your side' but this could have some other longer term affects for you proffesionally. As far as the Aufenthaltserlaubnis is concerned, I can find no minimum salary requirements attached to the Erwerbstätigkeit (ability to work). It's been over a decade since I had such a thing myself, and laws change, but I definitely don't remember anything like that when I was working. This would seem to be strictly a matter between you and your employer. Good luck.